# How to execute a method when user quit iOS application (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-lifecycle

I've been building iOS Music application and 
I'm using **MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()** to play music from the iTunes library of the device.

I tried **applicationWillTerminate** to stop the music player, and It didn't work, after doing some research that I found out After iOS 4 **applicationWillTerminate** method will *almost never get called, and we must do all the work in **applicationDidEnterBackground** method.

But my point is, I want my Music player to keep playing music when it enters to the background, and only stop the music when user force quit the application, How can I achieve this behavior ?

Comment: There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS application. more at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Important: The applicationWillTerminate: method is not called if your app is currently suspended.

Even if you develop your app using iOS SDK 4 and later, you must still be prepared for your app to be killed without any notification. The user can kill apps explicitly using the multitasking UI. In addition, if memory becomes constrained, the system might remove apps from memory to make more room. Suspended apps are not notified of termination but if your app is currently running in the background state (and not suspended), the system calls the applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate. Your app cannot request additional background execution time from this method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: Yes, But is there any way to achieve above functionality ?

Comment: sorry , I have solve this in my music app , but I use MPMediaPlayer

Comment: https://github.com/zhaofucheng1129/iOSBackgroundDemo/blob/master/iOSBackgroundDemo/AudioViewController.swift

Comment: How did you solve that ? Can you please explain it to me ?

Comment: I use following code that give in github link. using AVQueuePlayer of MPMediaItem